# Fedora upgrade failed, how to rollback

Tags: fedora, dnf

I just upgraded fedora from 33 to 34 and the installation hung at 92%. After a restart I can log in on the cmdline. If I try to rollback using 'dnf history rollback' it complains that it can't find certain fc33 rpms. What can I do next?

Comment: Reinstall and restore from your backup.

Comment: Try restarting the update? Diagnose why/where it got stuck. Perhaps it did not really got stuck, just running some very long process.